# ion-datetime always forces the date picker to be displayed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, datetimepicker

I use Ionic 6 with Angular. I want a time picker button for a stop watch functionality. Since I need only the time, and not the date, I have the following in my HTML:

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Start Time</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime display-format="h:mm A" picker-format="h:mm A" value="1990-02-19T07:43Z"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I just copy pasted this snippet from the official ionic sample at
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/blob/v4/src/demos/api/datetime/index.html

The above code works fine inside that sample, which is based on plain HTML/JS, using @ionic/core@4.7.4/
But when I plug this into my Ionic6/Angular code, it always displays the date picker with the bulky calendar. I do not have the need, nor the screen real estate, for the calendar. Changing the time format to something like `hh/mm` also does not have any effect.

How to make Ionic recognize the display format/picker format I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this

```
<ion-datetime presentation="time" displayFormat="h:mm" locale="en-US"></ion-datetime>
```

> ion-datetime will use the hour cycle that is specified by the locale
> property by default. For example, if locale is set to en-US, then
> ion-datetime will use a 12 hour cycle.

[more detail refer the ionic doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime)

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-twcjq6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: presentation="time" did the trick and the display now looks fine. Btw, I find it strange that this property is attached to the model, and not the view.

Comment: what do you mean by model and not in view? Sorry I couldn't get you. if you can please provide the stackblitz I will check.

Comment: I was referring to code like this from the official doc:

    <ion-datetime-button datetime="dtb1"></ion-datetime-button>

    <ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true">
      <ng-template>

        <ion-datetime id="dtb1"  presentation="time"></ion-datetime>
      </ng-template>
    </ion-modal>

This seems to violate the MVC architecture. The ion-datetime object holds the data, so it is the model. The ion-datetime-button is the display widget, which is the view. And it is the view that should normally contain any display format specifications.

Comment: can you provide the stackblitz link, please?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-ceaais?file=src/app/app.component.html